# How to escape new line operator for header function

Tags: php

I try to redirect to another page with `header()`, i try to commit a string to the new page. This is not a problem. However, if the string contains a new line operator `\n`, like in this example:

`header("Location: test.php?mystring=A\nB\nC");`

Then i get this error:

`Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\script.php on line 134`

Is there a way to mask the `\n` somehow?

Comment: With [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode).

Comment: Change `\n` to `%0A`